# How can I send an email programmatically when the order state was changed?

Tags: magento2, module, orders, email

I'm using the Magento 2.1.6.

I'd like to send automatically an email to the customer when I change the order state to a specific and custom state that I've created (e.g custom_state).

Like that to M1.

https://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/

How can I do that?

Thanks